# Intelllij IDEA 13 idea.exe.vmoptions file stock settings

Tags: intellij-idea

I screwed up and made changes to idea.exe.vmoptions after intalling Intellij IDEA 13.0, without making a backup copy of the original version of the file.  I would like to restore the file to its original settings.  Is there a way to restore vmoptions to its original state?  If not, what are the stock settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download the zip version of the IDE by replacing `.exe` with `.zip` in the download link, then unpack and overwrite the broken `.vmoptions` file with the vanilla copy, or just use this:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```